# Can't see the image or description on test opensea?

Tags: nft, rinkeby, opensea

I deployed my nft contract on rinkeby testnet and tested it. It was working flawlessly until today. The nft that I minted today is visible on my profile but the image is not visible. The name and description that
Were written  on the meta data not visible. If I click on the nft to set up for my profile picture, it shows invalid content.

NOW I am little confused what happened all of a sudden? Why it stopped working like it worked before? Is it a rinkeby problem? What will happen if I deploy my contract on ethereum mainnet?

Comment: Hi :) Could you share a link to the OpenSea item and/or the contract address and/or the link to the metadata?

Comment: https://testnets.opensea.io/collection/testnft-23kzrhypnu   - collection @Ziad Edher

Comment: https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmNcGsVLXNgCsT7YQMEYN1WUGA8saBACj3EHmB7GwQcQ1H . metadata

Comment: Meta data validation shows the link null

Comment: I see the metadata on OpenSea just fine now! This might have been a transient issue on OpenSea's side.